# Volume from rotating a functional relationship around a line?

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

I know how to rotate functions around lines, but a friend of mine proposed that what if I were to be presented a functional relationship that cannot be simplified, and asked what I would do in this case?

As an example, he proposed that I find the volume of the solid of revolution that arises when I rotate the relationship $x^2 + \sin(xy)+y^2=1$ around the line $x=2$.

I considered parameterizing the relationship and somehow integrating it that way, but this has come to nowhere.

Any thoughts at how I would approach this?

Comment: I doubt that this has a nice analytical solution. My guess is that you would try a numerical approach.

Comment: Such "relationships" are generally called "implicit curves" or "zero sets" or equivalent phrases, because they are the points $(x,y)$ such that $F(x,y) = 0$, where $F(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 +\sin xy -1$. As Andrei indicates, most likely the integral is not one you can solve by finding an anti-derivative (though I have not investigated if this is truly the case). Residue theory from complex analysis stands a good chance of finding an exact value here. But most likely, numerical integration is your best bet. Integration is very stable with respect to numerical techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really doubt this can be solved analytically so I will approach this numerically.

Here is the shape in question [image]

Recall that the volume of a solid of revolution generated by a planar shape $L$ is given by the area of $L$ times the distance $D$ the centroid of $L$ travels, as per Pappus's centroid theorem.

Hence, we just need to find these two components. Finding the area of $L$ is not hard, and we can do as follows. Given that $\mathbf{1}_{\chi}(x, y)$ is the indicator function of the set $\chi$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the area of $L$ is
$$ A=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\mathbf{1}_{x^2 + \sin(xy)+y^2\le1}(x, y)\text{ d}A$$
Accordingly, in mathematica, we set up a notebook like this

```
 In[1]:= ineq = x^2 + Sin[x*y] + y^2 <= 1
Out[1]:= x^2 + Sin[x*y] + y^2 <= 1
 In[2]:= NIntegrate[Boole[ineq], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive", AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8]
```

This should output

```
Out[2]:= 3.5123
 In[3]:= NumberForm[%2, 16]
Out[3]:= 3.512296577452417
```

Now for the centroid, common sense through inspection should show that it is exactly at the origin due to the symmetries of the shape. However, we can prove this as well. We don't care about the $y$ coordinate, since the revolution of the centroid around $x=2$ only depends on the $x$ coordinate.

The centroid's $x$ coordinate is given by
$$x_c = \frac{\displaystyle\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}x\cdot\mathbf{1}_{x^2 + \sin(xy)+y^2\le1}(x, y)\text{ d}A}{\displaystyle\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\mathbf{1}_{x^2 + \sin(xy)+y^2\le1}(x, y)\text{ d}A} = \frac{\displaystyle\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}x\cdot\mathbf{1}_{x^2 + \sin(xy)+y^2\le1}(x, y)\text{ d}A}{A}$$

Finding the top integral in mathematica returns $0$ as expected

```
 In[4]:= NIntegrate[x*Boole[ineq], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive", AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8]
Out[4]:= 0.
```

Since we revolve our shape $L$ in a circle, the centroid must also travel in a circle. The distance $L$'s centroid travel is hence $2\pi R$, where $R$ is the distance from the line $x=2$ to $x_c$, which is just $2$.

So, the total volume of your solid of revolution is nothing but (approximately) $$2\pi\cdot2\cdot A = 4\pi\cdot 3.512296577452417 = 44.13682...$$

Comment: Eh I guess a numerical solution is good enough. A friend of mine had proposed we use Lagrange inversion theorem to solve for $y$ and then do stuff with it but it seems too tedious for this lol so w/e